# Memory leak in Visual Studio in C

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management

I've got the following problem: I'm working with 2D arrays in visual studio 2015 and I've made a function to allocate memory and another to free it. Here they go:

```
double** MatrizAlloc(int nRow, int nCol)
{
   int i;
   double **field;
   field = (double **)calloc(nRow, sizeof(double *));
   if (!(field)) perror("Error alocating memory");
   for (i=0; i<nRow, i++)
   {
      field[i] = (double *)calloc(nCol, sizeof(double));
      if (!(field[i])) perror("Error alocating memory");
   }
   return field;
}

void MatrizDealloc(double **field, int nRow)
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<nRow, i++) 
       free(field[i]);
   free(field);
}
```

I've tried also reverse the free loop starting with (nRow-1) and ending in 0, but the results are the same. I can't see where is the memory leak or if there is a workaround. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What makes you believe there exists a memory leak?

Comment: I have a routine that uses a temporary matrix to perform a transformation (subsample the columns using a low-pass FIR filter) and I need a temporary matrix to store the result. So inside the function, I allocate the temporary matrix, use it, and deallocate in the end. The problem is before I call this function I have 106MB allocated to the process, and after it I have 112Mb. I've tracked down the memory usage and it grows from 106 to 127Mb when I create de temp matrix, keep the 127MB during the filtering and subsample, but does not return to 106MB when I deallocate it.

Comment: I've noticed it because I ran the process iteratively and ´I´ve got a memory overflow :it has consumed more than 2GB RAM!

Comment: I don't see a memory leak in the code you've shown. The problem is likely elsewhere, in the code you haven't shown. It would be best if you prepare a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated my Visual Studio to 2017 and it solved the problem. Perhaps it was some bug in the version I was using. Thanks!